# Gray Line To Migrate Questions About Similar Topic

Tags: support

I asked the question below:

[Latest Windows 10 Will Not Deploy Printers Per Computer](https://superuser.com/questions/1695164/latest-windows-10-will-not-deploy-printers-per-computer?noredirect=1#comment2606945_1695164)

Users are telling me it should be on ServerFault but on Serverfault I found a similar question that they migrated it Super User.

Is there a good rubric to go by to decide this kind of question?

And if it is supposed to be on ServerFault can it be migrated?

Comment: Migrated as per you request